# InAppBrowser loadstart event not firing / scope issues

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, phonegap, inappbrowser

*(This is a phonegap app, for iOS & Android, using JS/HTML/CSS)*

I open up links I want to use the inappbrowser using the class selector, 'external'.  So I have the below code to open up those links:

```
$("body").on("click", "a.external", function(){
    var thisHref = $(this).attr("href");
    appBrowser = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(thisHref, '_blank', 'location=no, zoom=no');
    appBrowser.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) { 
    if (event.url == "XXXXX") { appBrowser.close(); }
});
```

At the external URLs themselves, I set up links that link to 'XXXXX' that should close out the inAppBrowser.  Everything works 100% on the Phonegap Desktop emulator, but when I install the .apk or .ipa files on actual devices, loadstart doesn't get fired EXCEPT for the first initial click within the app.

This leads me to believe it's a scope issue, since it looks like the listener only picks up when the loadstart occurs directly after a click to a.external.  (P.S. appBrowser is defined globally [var appBrowser; at top]).

I'm not exactly sure how to arrange the code so that the listener gets attached, and continues working the entire time.  I have tried placing the addEventListener on its own, within deviceready function, or the whole thing within deviceready (neither work).

So I'm hoping there's something simple I'm missing here, and it is indeed a scope issue.   Strange though that it works as is on the emulator, but only on the first click on the devices themselves.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the relevant portions of how I have things setup in my phonegap project using InAppBrowser, which if I understand your question correctly is similar to how you want your setup.

*phonegap-bootstrap.js*

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
}
```

*when opening links*

```
window.open(url, '_system', 'location=yes');
```

I suppose you don't need the location flag, but that keeps the URL bar when you open your new window.  Hope that helps, I remember having to figure this out at some point, but any greater explanation I might have has been lost in my memory.

Comment: I am using inappbrowser only for links marked with the class 'external', hence the .on function above.  I do not want to call _system, as that would open up Chrome separately (want to make it appear 'all within' the app itself, hence the _blank, or _self).  My issue I believe is the .addEventListener losing scope, or stopping working after the very first click.

Comment: Ok, sorry, a little different than what I'm doing.  Just an idea looking at your code though is reference the event object from the jquery selector/handler, so it has a preventDefault() on it.  `$('..').on('click',function(event){event.preventDefault()})`... not sure if that'll help, but maybe worth trying.